# Looking for a self-hosted tool to collect yearly registration fees for a charity

Tags: web-apps

I found several tools for organizing events, but none for what I need. Maybe I'm not using the right search keywords.

I need a piece of software to be linked to a phpmyadmin database. The web interface would allow people to become members of the association by paying a yearly fee. New users could register by filling in a form and paying this fee. Ancient users would automatically receive an email reminder when their registration is about to end and a link to renew it.

The admin could at any time see the list of registered members.

Please, do you know of any such tool? Preferably open source but we will pay for a license if we have to.

There are web sites which offer to do this for people, but we don't want something external. We are looking for a self-hosted solution.

Comment: As payment is involved a fully self-hosted solution is difficult because you have to link it to your bank account. So it depends on the bank where the account is hosted, the money should to payed to. Typically payment transactions are preformed by service provider as providing the different payment methods is complex.

Comment: We plan to use Paypal. Putting a Paypal button on a web site is not too difficult.

Answer (score 0):

We are currently using https://www.helloasso.com
It does the job. It's in French and specific for French administrations requirements. Whenever someone registers, this site tries to incite him or her to also register to some other non-profits.

I might get round to coding some such script one day...